# Laravel, Composer: File autoload not working

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I use Laravel 5.4 and want to autoload a helpers.php file with helper  functions that I want to use all over my project (but especially in my controllers).

My composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Http/helpers.php"
        ],
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "files": [
            "app/Http/helpers.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

My helpers.php looks like:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http;

function combineColumnNameType($columnLabels, $columnTypes) {
    $combined = [];
    // logic
    return $combined;
}
```

My problem is, that when I try to use a function of helpers.php in one of my Controllers it throws the following error message:

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\combineColumnNameType()
```

I tried to `composer dump-autoload` a couple times, but it's not helping.

I also tried `composer update`.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `composer.json` looks fine, but it looks like you're using helpers wrong. Helper function should be a simple function which looks like this:

```
if (! function_exists('myCustomHelper')) {
    function myCustomHelper()
    {
        return 'Hey, it\'s working!';
    }
}
```

And you should call it with `myCustomHelper()` and not `$this->myCustomHelper()`.

**Update**

The `helpers.php` shouldn't have `namespace` or class definition.

Comment: @J.B. it shouldn't have namespace or class. Also, how do you use the helper in a controller?

Comment: i just call the function like so `combineColumnNameType(User::$labels, User::$columnTypes)`

Comment: ahh, the namespace broke it. Without its working fine. Can you edit your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @J.B. I've added this to my answer. Gald it helped. )